# Getting " TypeError: triggerElement is null " error in magento on product page using calendar

Tags: javascript, magento, calendar, prototype

i am facing this error
"
TypeError: triggerElement is null

triggerElement.onclick = function() {
"
 when I installed a booking module on magento v-1.8.1.0.

which is using a calendar for its functionality.

```
    Calendar.setup = function(params)
{

  function param_default(name, def) {
    if (!params[name]) params[name] = def
  }

  param_default('dateField', null)
  param_default('triggerElement', null)
  param_default('parentElement', null)
  param_default('selectHandler',  null)
  param_default('closeHandler', null)

  // In-Page Calendar
  if (params.parentElement)
  {
    var calendar = new Calendar(params.parentElement)
    calendar.setSelectHandler(params.selectHandler || Calendar.defaultSelectHandler)
    if (params.dateFormat)
      calendar.setDateFormat(params.dateFormat)
    if (params.dateField) {
      calendar.setDateField(params.dateField)
      calendar.parseDate(calendar.dateField.innerHTML || calendar.dateField.value)
    }
    calendar.show()
    return calendar
  }
```

// Popup Calendars
  //
  // XXX There is significant optimization to be had here by creating the
  // calendar and storing it on the page, but then you will have issues with
  // multiple calendars on the same page.

```
else
  {
    var triggerElement = $(params.triggerElement || params.dateField)
    triggerElement.onclick = function() { 
      var calendar = new Calendar()
      calendar.setSelectHandler(params.selectHandler || Calendar.defaultSelectHandler)
      calendar.setCloseHandler(params.closeHandler || Calendar.defaultCloseHandler)
      if (params.dateFormat)
        calendar.setDateFormat(params.dateFormat)
      if (params.dateField) {
        calendar.setDateField(params.dateField)
        calendar.parseDate(calendar.dateField.innerHTML || calendar.dateField.value)
      }
      if (params.dateField)
        Date.parseDate(calendar.dateField.value || calendar.dateField.innerHTML, calendar.dateFormat)
        calendar.showAtElement(triggerElement)
      return calendar
    }
  }

}
```

I am getting this error on page load, can anybody please guide me in debugging this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passed `params` in the function did you check that it contains `params.triggerElement` and `params.dateField`, because if this line

> var triggerElement = $(params.triggerElement || params.dateField)

assigns `null` to `triggerElement` then you will get the error that you are getting.

After this line `var triggerElement = $(params.triggerElement || params.dateField)` you can put a `null` check and create the element if not created before binding a click event.

Comment: Thank u, `var triggerElement = $(params.triggerElement || params.dateField)` was returning null
 cause of the error was a jquery conflict, added jQuery,noConflict() code and replaced $ with jQuery in that line of code and problem solved